# Illegal option: -cacerts for keytool in gitlab-ci with gradle:jdk8

Tags: java, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, keytool

I use the next configuration in gitlab-ci.yml :

```
image: gradle:jdk11
stages:
  - build
  - publish
before_script:
  - wget -P /tmp http://www.some.com/SOME.crt
 - keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file /tmp/SOME.crt -cacerts -alias "Some" -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

All works fine. But I need to change java version to 8. I edit my configuration to `image: gradle:jdk8` and got error:

```
....
Illegal option: -cacerts
```

My gitlab configuration understanding is very poor. How I can fix configuration to use image gradle:jdk8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`keytool -importcert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/keytool.htm#GUID-5990A2E4-78E3-47B7-AE75-6D1826259549__KEYTOOL_OPTION_IMPORTCERT) command does have a `-cacerts` option, but I never seen it used in combination with `-trustcacerts`.

The documentation does mention:

> ```
> -cacerts cacerts
> ```
>
> Operates on the cacerts keystore.
>   This option is  equivalent to "`-keystore path_to_cacerts -storetype type_of_cacerts`".
>
> An error will be reported if the `-keystore` or `-storetype` option is used with the `-cacerts` option.

Comment: No, -cacerts appeared in java 9, it is absent in java 8 tools: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#keytool_option_importcert

Comment: @ValeriyK.That is why I never seen it :) Since your image uses jdk8, that would explain the error.

Comment: Yes, I think I should try -keystore path_to_cacerts -storetype type_of_cacerts

Comment: @ValeriyK. Exactly: the equivalent of what `-cacerts` is supposed to be a shortcut for.

Answer (score 4):

I found solution when googling 'keytool import crt to jks' [here](https://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/security/tools/understanding-java-keytool-working-with-crt-files-fixing-certificate-problems) :

```
keytool -importcert -file my.cert.location/my.cert.crt -storepass changeit -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias mycert1
```

-keystore must be default java keystore location – $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts. It works for gradle:jdk8. I can build and publish with these keytool options. This command adds .crt certificate to default java cert storage.

Comment: Yes, but it took some time to found the value. I searched storetype value and found that only a few types exist. One of these jks, and .crt it does not belong to any storetype. So I started to search 'crt to jks' and found the working solution.